# Click an item on a listbox then do some actions

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

Currently I have it so when a user selects an item from the listbox, then presses a button, labels show with some text about the item

However I want it to be so when the user selects/clicks on an item from the listbox, it'll show the info in the labels then. and change whenever they click a different item. So far I have this but it doesn't do anything?  Am I using the correct method? Or maybe I've got something wrong with my inside code.

```
 private void lbCart_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
         {

            string curItem = lbGames.SelectedItem.ToString();


            int index = lbGames.FindString(curItem);
            ratingLbl.Text = "Rating: " + ratingList[index];
            priceLbl.Text = "Price: " + priceList[index];
        }
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem.  Everything seems to be working fine for me.  (FYI you can use `lbGames.SelectedIndex` instead of finding the string.)  What do you mean when you say "it doesn't do anything"?

Comment: Firstly I just realised I was using the wrong lb name, I used lbCart intstead of lbGames. I changed it to that but still doesn't work. When I click on an item in the lbGames, nothing shows up in the labels.

Comment: I had that exact code but I used it in a button method , so when I selected an item and pressed the button it showed the info in the labels. But doesn't seem to work when I just want to select an item (without pressing a button)

Comment: I took out the code I had inside of the SelectedIndexChanged method and just put a messagebox to see if it does anything when I select an item but it does nothing still

Comment: Please check carefully to which listbox this code is connected. Look at the event properties of the correct listbox in designer mode and check that its selectedindexchanged event is showing this method. If it isn't, you can select it from the drop-down. The name of the method is irrelevant; by convention it is of the form Controlname_event (the designer generates it like this when you double click a control).

Comment: Hi, that sounds like it would work. However I'm not sure where to find the event properties. I've clicked the listbox and I'm looking on the Properties panel but don't see anything about selectedindexchanged event

Comment: Nevermind, got it to work now. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off I think you want lbCart inside your event handler not lbGames (since you are subscribing to the lbCart SelectedIndexChange event)

Secondly are you subscribing to the event?

Xaml: `SelectedIndexChanged="lbCart_SelectedIndexChanged"`

or code behind `lbCart.SelectedIndexChanged += lbCart_SelectedIndexChanged;`